# OpenMapTiles: Generate boundary admin_level 6 at lower zoom levels

Tags: openstreetmap, openmaptiles

I am wanting to show admin_level 6 boundaries at lower zoom levels (8, 7, 6), currently they start showing at zoom level 9.

I realize that I need to modify the import script so that this data is saved into the .mbtiles file. I have edited the [boundary.sql](https://github.com/openmaptiles/openmaptiles/blob/ff99a02aae287ed0546abe705c981e71c8618c33/layers/boundary/boundary.sql) file to change `WHERE admin_level <= 4` to `WHERE admin_level <= 6` for `boundary_z6`, `boundary_z7` and `boundary_z8`.

I see the .sh file at `/var/lib/docker/overlay/d9c758ee5fef79d79f0412880332a2efe66fd5c3d9614d6a710211c87e7bc04c/root/usr/src/app/import_osmborder_lines.sh`, however I don't know if that will be overwritten at some point?

However, after a new import boundaries are still not shown at levels 8, 7, 6.

Looking deeper, it appears that I need to also modify the [import_osmborder_lines.sh](https://github.com/openmaptiles/import-osmborder/blob/master/import/import_osmborder_lines.sh) script so those lines get imported, but that is in its own docker file that I don't know how to edit so the `quickstart.sh` will use it.

**How can I edit the `import-osmborder` docker file and have my `quickstart.sh` script use this for import? Or, am I going about this completely wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up editing the `import_osmborder_lines.sh` that is in the `/var/lib/docker/` directory. This worked, but I still am not sure this is the ideal method.